# Update value for all objects in collection Meteor

Tags: meteor, collections, coffeescript

I have a meteor program that I am working on and I have a collection for Teachers.

I can update their pay with the following snippet

```
MyTeacherCollection.update {_id: teacherId}, $set:
  payRate: newPayrate
```

But that is only one teacher at a time, I was wondering how if there is an easy way to apply a 5% raise to all the teacher 's salary in my collection.

Comment: Important clarification: does the 5% raise depend on the current value in each teacher document? It's unclear if `newPayrate` is a percentage or a salary. A clear answer can be provided if you give some sample documents and the desired outcome for each.

Comment: Yes, The 5% pay raise will be applied to whatever they already make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each teacher's salary differs you need to iterate over the collection:

```
MyTeacherCollection.find().forEach(t => {
  const oldRate = t.payRate;
  MyTeacherCollection.update(t._id,{ $set: { payRate: oldRate*1.05 }});
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you